# jquery sortable not picking up by padding in full-screen

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got some connected, sortable lists working pretty well. When I've got my browser window in half-screen, then I can even pick up the list items by clicking on the padding, which is what I would like. However, when I maximize the browser window, then I can only pick up the list item by its text. This is awkward and user-unfriendly. I would like the padding to function as the "hit area" no matter the window size. So far, I've only tested this in Chrome.

**The view: seatingChart.html.erb**

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class = "row">
        <% @students.in_groups(6).each do |group| %>
            <div class = "col-md-2">
                <ul class='sortable-list'>
                <% group.each do |student| %>
                    <% if student %>
                        <li class="sortable-item">
                            <%= student.firstPlusInit %>
                        </li>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
                </td>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**coffeescript with jquery: seminars.coffee**

```
ready = ->
    $('.sortable-list').sortable({connectWith: '.first-column', placeholder: 'my-placeholder'})

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

**css:**

```
.sortable-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px; 
  border-radius: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.my-placeholder {
  list-style-type: decimal;
  background: #AAFFAA;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

**Applicable method from model: student.rb**

```
# Returns first name with limit plus last initial
def firstPlusInit
    "#{first_name[0,15]} #{last_name[0,1]}" 
end
```

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is CSS & Bootstrap related. The `col-md-*` class has a `float` property on large screens, but not on smaller screens

Comment: You're right. I played around with all of my CSS settings. The problem fixed when I cut the line: "text-align: center". So now that part is working. I'll keep looking for a way to make it work with centered text.

Comment: If you could post (as a new question) a [minimal, viable and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the css problem you are having with bootstrap combined with your custom css & html, then SO may be able to help